# How to get information in one HTML class, before another using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

On this website: https://www.theyworkforyou.com/mp/10001/diane_abbott/hackney_north_and_stoke_newington/votes

I'm trying to pull all of the text within each ul class "vote-description" entry, but only the text that comes prior to the a class tags - I.E, everything before

I have code that will pull everything from inside the entry, shown here:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import *

response = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.theyworkforyou.com/mp/10001/diane_abbott/hackney_north_and_stoke_newington/votes")
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

desc = soup.findAll('ul',{'class':"vote-descriptions"})
for line in desc:
print line.findAll('li')
```

How can I alter this code to exclude everything other than the part before the 'a' tag. For example, the first list entry found is:

```
<li> Generally voted for equal <b>gay rights</b> <a class="vote-description__source" href="/mp/10001/diane_abbott/hackney_north_and_stoke_newington/divisions?policy=826">Show votes</a> <a class="vote-description__evidence" href="/mp/10001/diane_abbott/hackney_north_and_stoke_newington/divisions?policy=826">11 votes for, 1 vote against, 15 absences, between 1999&ndash;2014</a>
</li>
```

But what I want to print is:

```
Generally voted for equal <b>gay rights</b>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `contents` [BeautifulSoup Doc - .contents and .children](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children)

```
for line in desc:
    li_list = line.findAll('li')
    for li in li_list:
        print "%s%s" % (li.contents[0],li.b)
```

Test

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ="""<li> Generally voted for equal <b>gay rights</b> <a class="vote-description__source" href="/mp/10001/diane_abbott/hackney_north_and_stoke_newington/divisions?policy=826">Show votes</a> <a class="vote-description__evidence" href="/mp/10001/diane_abbott/hackney_north_and_stoke_newington/divisions?policy=826">11 votes for, 1 vote against, 15 absences, between 1999&ndash;2014</a></li>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for line in soup.findAll('li'):
    print "%s%s" % (line.contents[0],line.b)
```

Output

```
$ python test.py 
Generally voted for equal  <b>gay rights</b>
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much.